# Outlook 2013 rule to move the sent files to specific folder month wise

Tags: outlook, rule

My requirement is
one of my user wants to move his sent mails to a specific folder month wise...means all mails he sent in May month should move to may month & same for June, July & current month...when month changes folder also change...

Answer (score 1):

When `Application.ItemSend` event fires, retrieve the folder and set it to the `MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder` property of the message being sent.